# Handling CORS when using django, angular and gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, django, gulp

I have a project which I am building on top of Django and using AngularJS 1 to handle the front-end. Furthermore I am trying to use Gulp so I can enjoy some browser Sync features. Below is a piece of code that I am using to fire the Gulp server but at the same time using the Django server as a proxy.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost:8000"
});
});
```

However I am running into an issue with CORS. The error message I am getting is the following:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/static/js/data.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

The **data.json** file in question is the one I am using as a source of data for my front-end developoment as I have not created my back-end yet.

Here is an example of how i am getting data from the JSON file using Angular's $HTTP:

```
marksApp.factory('getSubjectsService', ['$http',function($http){
return {
    getSubjectNames : function(stdNum){
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/static/js/data.json')
        .then(function(data){
            return data.data;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/server.html - how to enable CORS on a multitude of server environments

Comment: @JaromandaX looking at my question, do I need to fix the CORS issue in django, angular or gulp

Comment: you need to enable CORS on the server from which you want to allow cross origin resource sharing - `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Let me look around for how to do that with the django server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CORS headers to your Django response.

There is a popular Django app called `django-cors-headers` that can simplify that. Check https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: I tried this and it would not work. I have a stand alone js file on my server and from the error it seems its on this file that i need to enable the cors. Is there any way it is possible to add CORS headers to a json file?

Comment: CORS headers should be added on the server side. Have you tried `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` . or setiing `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ()` appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I'm using http-proxy-middleware to proxy.

I have a django rest framework here:

```
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

And the gulp proxy here:

```
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');
..snip..
server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/api', {target: 'http://localhost:8000', changeOrigin: true});
```

The result, in my case, is localhost:3000/api proxies to localhost:8000/api, so you won't need CORS headers.

Something like this should work for you:

```
$http.get('/static/js/data.json')

server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/static', {target: 'http://localhost:8000', changeOrigin: true});
```

Good luck.

See: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/v0.9.0/README.md